# How to search data in multiple fields / columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried a code like this, it works quite well:

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<InternProject.Models.Course>
....
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Course", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        @Html.TextBox("searching")
        <input type="submit"  value="search" />

    </p>
} 
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Course ID</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Specialization</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.crs_ID)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.crs_Course)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.crs_Major)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.crs_Specialization)</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.crs_ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.crs_ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.crs_ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class CourseController : Controller
{
    private DbCourse db = new DbCourse();
    public ActionResult Index(string submit, string searching)
    {
        var course = from x in db.Course select x;
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searching))
        {
            return View(db.Course.Where(x => x.crs_Course.Contains(searching.Trim()) ||
                         x.crs_Major.Contains(searching.Trim()) || 
                         x.crs_Specialization.Contains(searching.Trim())).ToList());
        }
        else if (searching == null)
        {
            return View(db.Course.Where(x => x.crs_Course == searching || searching.Trim() == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Course.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

But the `id` cannot be included because it is an integer. I want to have a solution wherein I can search also in the `id` of my database depending on the input in the search box.

Also, is there a better code than this for a simple search functionality like this? I've noticed it's so long and it obviously violates the DRY principle.

Here is what my simple application looks like:
[image]

I'm taking my baby steps in ASP.NET MVC as a beginner.

I hope to improve my knowledge using applied coding and not just relying on tutorial videos.
Thank you very much in advance! =)

Comment: Why can't you simply search by:
Convert.ToInt32(searching.Trim())
?

Comment: Why not a textbox for each column?

Comment: Also the code in your `else if (searching == null)` block does not make sense.

Comment: And since you seem to be loading all records in the initial page, you would be far better implementing  JavaScript to just hide rows which do not match rather than making multiple requests back to the server

Comment: I don't have knowledge yet on how I can apply Javascript in MVC. However your statement makes sense on a general scale. Thank you very much!

Comment: A [simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) of using javascript

Comment: And as a side note, you clearly have not tested your code very well since if you hit the `else if` block the `searching.Trim() == null` would throw an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to convert the ID to a string. Your code then become the following.

```
return View(db.Course.Where(x => x.crs_Course.Contains(searching.Trim()) ||
                     x.crs_Major.Contains(searching.Trim()) || 
                     x.crs_Specialization.Contains(searching.Trim()) ||
                     x.crs_crs_ID.ToString().Contains(searching.Trim())).ToList())
```

This doesn't go against the DRY principle since you're using Contains() on different variables; however, what is going against the DRY principle is the repetitive searching.Trim(). I suggest you trim the string once at the top of your code.

```
var match = searching.Trim();
```

Then you can use match instead of searching.Trim() in the code below.

Comment: I have yet to try the code you suggested, but the solution regarding the DRY principle problem makes sense. I'll try that. Thank you very much!